# linq query as datagrid source

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have a linq query:

```
var query = from myumowa_typy in ArUmowy_typy
            select new
            {
                myumowa_typy.Umowa_nazwa,
                myumowa_typy.Umowa_raport,
                czas_umowy_w_miesiącach = myumowa_typy.Ile_miesiecy_cała_umowa,
                obniżony_abonament_w_miesiącach = myumowa_typy.Ile_miesiecy_abonament_obnizony
            };`
```

How can I make this query to be source of datagrid ? I want headers in my datagrid to be taken from this query and of course data. And in future I want to add some parameters to my query to filter results. I'm using wpf and liq ado entities.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687959/bind-wpf-datagrid-to-linq-query-entity-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid`:

```
var query = (from myumowa_typy in ArUmowy_typy
        select new
        {
            myumowa_typy.Umowa_nazwa,
            myumowa_typy.Umowa_raport,
            czas_umowy_w_miesiącach = myumowa_typy.Ile_miesiecy_cała_umowa,
            obniżony_abonament_w_miesiącach = myumowa_typy.Ile_miesiecy_abonament_obnizony
        }).ToList();

dataGrid1.ItemsSource = query;
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" />
```

Comment: Now I have an error:

Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'ArUmowy_typy'.  'Select' not found.

Comment: If ArUmowy_typy is a DbSet, it should be context.ArUmowy_typy where context is your DbContext. Also, I just copied the code you posted, so if it doesn't work it didn't work before either.

Comment: Thanks, I have change my code to give good context:
            ARWAL_daneEntities4 myARWAL_DaneEntities = new ARWAL_daneEntities4();


Now it works ok